# Finding the correct infrared signal for a device with lirc

Tags: lirc

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to turn on/off a beamer, for which I have captured the IR-signals from the remote with lirc.
Now I want to control my old stereo too, for which I don't have the remote anymore. (Onkyo TX-SV373) How can I find out with lirc the correct IR-signal to be send to turn it on/off? I couldn't find any list of IR-signals for the stereo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the config file for the remote here: http://lirc-remotes.sourceforge.net/remotes-table.html
It works perfectly.